# How to deal with ng-repeat and lots of items?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a web application that shows a log in real-time. That means, the log is still being written, and I'd like to update the UI accordingly.

At the moment, I solved it by using an array and showing it using `ng-repeat`. I don't need two-way bindings, it's just showing a simple list, but - as said - with updates. The updates don't always happen at the very start or very end of the list, but may also happen in between (don't ask why, it's just the way it is).

Basically, my approach works - but once we have a few hundred log messages, the app starts to get very, very slow.

How could I deal with this issue?

Of course, I could write my own directive which just takes the array, concatenates it and writes it to the HTML, but this wouldn't reflect changes in real-time, would it?

Comment: please show some code

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I've dealt with this in the past. One easy, and one hard.

The easy way:

Write a filter and have your ng-repeat grab it's entries from it.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="object in objects | myFilter:amount"></div>
```

In the filter have it send back just the latest based on an amount (so if you have 1000, and the amount is 50, send back the latest 50). If you need the whole thing wire up a button that toggles the amount to everything (or zero, or whatever). Downside is you won't see everything, and when you do need to is when you'll see the load.

The hard way:

You'd have to write a directive that takes your entries. Based on the scroll position and the height of each log entry (are they all the same (easier)? or dynamic(harder)) have a subset of the elements displayed on the screen offset by the padding of the ones preceding them. This can get very tricky, very fast but I have implemented and have run grid components on tablets with >100,000 entries. Only about 40 are buffered and as you scroll the top ones get knocked off and new ones get in. I put a couple screens worth in there just as backup in case they scroll too fast.

I can't just drop the code in there for how to do that as it's pretty tricky and would have to be tailored to your specific app.